# How do I get the size of a particular table in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

How do I get the size of a particular table which is in a particular database in MySQL database?

For example i uploaded three images i want the total size of the images which is in images table in size KB OR MB

Comment: What do you mean by `size`? number or rows? size in byte?

Comment: you mean rows of table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to understand your question better. By "size", do you mean the size on disk, or the number of rows?

Comment: i uploaded  two images i want total size like in KB or MB.

Comment: @harishjain: You upload the base64 of the image or just the path to the image?

Comment: i uploaded the images in table called images in database and i can see that the images are been inserted in my database but im not getting the exact size of all images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query below:

```
SELECT 
    table_name AS `Table`, 
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "dbname"
    AND table_name = "tablename"
```

Comment: i already used this code im still not getting sir. i uploaded two images i want total size like in KB or MB

Comment: What are you getting if not the size in MB?

Comment: For example i uploaded one image it  is showing 1Mb again if i i upload two more images it is still showing only 1MB but total sizes of images are more than 1 MB